# Store data periodically in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, file, sharedpreferences

I need to record a change in my boolean variable that depends on certain conditions in my code. I have    a timertask that runs every second to track any such change. When a change occurs, i.e., when the variable change say from 'true' to 'false', I need to save the time at which this event happened. All of these events need to be able to retrieved from another Activity at a later time.  I can implement this task either using SharedPreferences: I was thinking about using the putstring method:

```
sp_editor.putString("alarm_activated",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

but I realized alarm_activated is overridden each time. But I need all the 'time' values.
I could also change the key each time (key,value) by adding the 'time' to the key itself as below.

```
sp_editor.putStrng("alarm_activated"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis(),placeholder);
```

This looks like a really inefficient way to do it.

Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is to set up and update an SQLite database your app can use. It will give you maximum flexibility in terms of saving and retrieving data locally without worrying about loosing data if the app gets killed. Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: Is it wise to store SQLite data every second? I am also running two other concurrent threads.

Comment: Why would you store the data every second? just store when your event occurs.

Comment: That's true but the event can potentially occur every second although less likely. Can I just use a new thread to update SQLite database?

Comment: You should use the same instance of an Async task to update a database. If you need help with this sorta stuff, you should ask another question as this isn't exactly within the scope of this one.

Answer (score -1):

Create a singleton class and inside create ListArray where you can save data.

If it data need to be accessible from another App use Android SQLite.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class like this.

```
public class TimeKeeper {
private static TimeKeeper instance;

public List<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();

public static TimeKeeper getTimeKeeper() {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new TimeKeeper();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

From your TimerTask you can add time to the list as

```
TimeKeeper.getTimeKeeper().timeList.add("Your Time");
```

and from any other activity you can access this same list very easily.

Mark as up if it works for you.

//======= For Saving it permanently you can loop through it and save it into db.

```
for(Strng time :TimeKeeper.getTimeKeeper().timeList)
 {
   db.insertTime(time); //call Your method to insert time string into your db
 }
```

Comment: If the app gets killed, all recorded data will get erased. I wouldn't use this solution.